# Проблема с кодировкой в DisplayAttribute в LabelFor методе

Tags: c#, кодировка, mvc

Разрабатываю MVC приложение и столкнулся с проблемой отображения значения `DisplayName` атрибута у моделей.

### Суть

у меня есть модальное окно, которое представляет форму редактирования некой модели. Далее я открываю ещё одно модальное окно из текущего для редактирования объекта дочерней модели. Так вот во втором модальном окне вместо нормального отображения `label` к `input` формы, выводятся кракозябры, хотя в родительском окне всё нормально. В итоге имею вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас где-то каким-то образом не используется Unicode?

Comment: Если у вас используется 2015 студия, то проверьте кодировку файла с исходником (там, где записаны атрибуты DisplayName). Roslyn не дружит с другими кодировками исходников и может выдавать такие неожиданные результаты.